# Continuity of the mapping $\left| \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-x/y}} - \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-y/x}} \right|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to figure out if the mapping
$$
f(x,y) := \left| \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-x/y}} - \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-y/x}} \right|
$$
on the domain
$$
(x,y) \in \Omega := (0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)
$$
is continuous, when setting $f(x,x) := 0$ for $x>0$.

Numerical evaluation with Maple and Mathematica let me assume that this mapping actually is continuous on the domain $\Omega$...but a rigorous proof, or at least some analytical reasoning, would be quite helpful here. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that $g(t)=t^{1/(1-t)}$ is a continuous function in $(0,1)\cup (1,+\infty)$ and 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}g(t)=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad \lim_{t\to 1}g(t)=\lim_{s\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)^s=e^{-1}.$$
Hence $g$ can be extended to a function $\overline{g}$ which is continuous in $[0,+\infty)$.
Moreover for all $(x,y) \in \Omega$,
$$f(x,y)= \left| \overline{g}\left( \frac{x}{y} \right) - \overline{g}\left( \frac{y}{x} \right) \right|.$$

Comment: Hey RobertZ! First of all, thanks for editing my question's title ;-) I completely forgot that!
I've also found the limits and the continuous extension that you've mentioned. By L'Hopital, the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to y} f(x,y)$ exists and equals $0$ for $(x,y) \in \Omega$, hence $f$ is in fact continuous on the line $\{ (x,x) | x \in \Omega \}$ and therefore on all of $\Omega$, if I'm right...the only problem now is continuity at the origin. Introducing polar coordinates $x = r \cdot \cos(\phi), y = r \cdot \sin(\phi)$ yields that $f$ is not continuous there...or do I miss something here?

Comment: @ComplexFlo But $(0,0)\not\in \Omega$.Moreover for $y=2x$ and $y=3x$ we get different limits as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Oh my god, sorry for that mistake! Of course, the origin doesn't matter here when asking for continuity on $\Omega$ ... Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: For the sake of completeness: The "line" that I'm talking about in my first comment to RobertZ's answer has to be $\{(x,x) \ | \ x > 0 \}$ of course!

Answer (score 1):

The mapping
$$
f(x,y) := \left| \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-x/y}} - \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-y/x}} \right|
$$
on the domain
$$
(x,y) \in \Omega := (0, \infty) \times (0, \infty)
$$
is continuous, since it is composition of power functions that they are continuous except on $y=x$. On this line we see 
$$\lim_{y\to x}\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)^{\frac{1}{1-x/y}}=\dfrac1e$$
by L'Hopital, and
$$\lim_{y\to x}f(x,y)=0$$
shows this function is continuous on $y=x$.